# Function with a pointer in its declaration. Why?

Tags: c, pointers

Not sure if the title explains it. What is the difference between:

```
char *s_gets(char * st, int n);
```

and

```
char s_gets(char * st, int n);
```

I would like to ask also why is there a pointer in the function declaration in the first place? What is its purpose?

Comment: [Explanation can be found here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: How else would you return a pointer from a function?

Comment: @Olaf with a `**` argument?

Comment: @It still would be a pointer, wouldn't it? (But yes, that's a typical beginner's function: `void f(int **);` ... :-}

Answer (score 4):

- `char s_gets(char * st, int n);` returns a character, that's all.
- `char *s_gets(char * st, int n);` returns a pointer to a character, which can be interpreted as a pointer to a string, if it is the programmer's will.

Comment: @KeithThompson that's why I said it can be interpreted as one, if it is what the programmer wants. Edit: ok, got what you meant, thanks.

Comment: Decent answer to a crap question.

Comment: I would reduce it to "`char` and `char*` are different types".

Answer (score 1):

```
char *s_gets(char * st, int n);
```

returns a pointer to `char`, while

```
char s_gets(char * st, int n);
```

returns a plain `char`.

> I would like to ask also why is there a pointer in the function declaration in the first place? What is its purpose?

It indicates that the function returns a *pointer* value.

C declaration syntax uses something called a *declarator* to convey the pointer-ness, array-ness, function-ness, or combination thereof of an item.  For example, take the declaration

```
int *p;
```

The *type* of `p` is `int *` (pointer to `int`).  The type is specified by the combination of the type specifier `int` and the *declarator* `*p`.  The `int`-ness of `p` is given by the type specifier `int` and the pointer-ness is given by the declarator `*p`.

If you substitute `p` with `f(void)`, you get

```
int *f(void);
```

The type of `f` is "function returning pointer to `int`".  The pointer-ness and function-ness of `f` are specified with the declarator `*f(void)`.

For any type *`T`* and any declarator *`D`*, the following are true:

```
T D;        // D is an instance of T
T D[N];     // D is an array of T
T D();      // D is a function returning T

T *D;       // D is a *pointer* to T
T *D[N];    // D is an array of pointers to T
T *D();     // D is a function returning a pointer to T

T (*D)[N];  // D is a pointer to an array of T
T (*D)();   // D is a pointer to a function returning T
```

In both declarations and expressions, the postfix `[]` subscript and `()` function-call operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*a[N]` will always be parsed as `*(a[N])` (array of pointers).  To declare something as a pointer *to an array* or a pointer *to a function*, you need to explicitly group the `*` operator with the declarator using parentheses.

Declarators can get arbitrarily complex:

```
T (*D())[N];      // D is a function returning a pointer to an array of T
T (*D[N])();      // D is an array of pointers to functions returning T
T *(*(*D)[N])[M]; // D is a pointer to an array of pointers to an array of pointers to T
```